# Is it possible to just take a normal (continuous) laser diode and pulse it? Or does this not produce the same effect as pulsed laser diodes?

Tags: laser, laser-diode, laser-driver

At the moment, I am planning for a project involving lasers (yes, I have been lectured on laser safety). I am looking for a cheap way to build a pulsed laser in the near-infrared range. Since laser diodes are typically relatively cheap, I thought that it would do well in satisfying this requirement of my project. I managed to find a relatively cheap laser diode of appropriate wavelength, but it is not pulsed. Is it possible to just take a normal (continuous) laser diode and pulse it (by building an appropriate pulsed laser driver, or something)? Or does this not produce the same effect as pulsed laser diodes? If this is indeed practically feasible, then how can one go about doing this (links to resources/information are appreciated)?

Comment: Link to the data sheet of the device.

Comment: @Andyaka I added a hyperlink, but I'm really asking generally.

Comment: Well, to answer would need a knowledge of what a pulsed laser is intended to do and that is more suitable for physics SE. I asked for the data sheets to see if the laser you chose could be pulsed and at what frequency in case this might be relevant to your application. If it's a general question on why lasers are pulsed this is the wrong site.

Comment: Do you want "modulated" (varying brightness, on or off) or do you actually want "pulsed" (short bursts of very high power, exceeding the maximum continuous rating)? What are you pointing it at?

Comment: @pjc50 Pulsed, not modulated.

Comment: That laser does not have an adequate data sheet in that the information on that link doesn't give me any confidence about its reliability. You should look for a laser with a pdf data sheet.

Comment: @Andyaka I am not asking *why* lasers are pulsed. My question is as I said: "Is it possible to just take a normal (continuous) laser diode and pulse it (by building an appropriate pulsed laser driver, or something)?" I am asking if this is generally possible with continuous-wave laser diodes.

Comment: Well given that you can turn it on then some time later turn it off and repeat that process, that would constitute pulsing a laser. As to whether than meets your requirements is unclear.

Comment: @Andyaka You just described what "pulsed" means in photonics, and then you ask me whether I just want it to "turn on and off" ...

Comment: Listen, I have no idea what a pulsed laser is intended to do. I can see that it can be turned on and off but that may not constitute all that is necessary in the world of people who pulse lasers. I modulate lasers and that is different. So, describe what you feel should fully constitute the requirements for a pulsed laser source and you might get some answers. As for me, I don't recognize the item you linked as being reliable. I wouldn't buy it on the info you linked - that is my two-penneth.

Comment: Well, it's a thermal management problem; you can overdrive it and it will almost certainly work, but by how much can you do this before it destroys the die? You either buy a batch of them and characterise this yourself, or find one where the manufacturer has already done this.

Comment: @Andyaka Oops, I confused pjc50's comment with yours. My apologies. I meant  "short bursts of very high power", which is the purpose of pulsed lasers in a photonics context.

Comment: @pjc50 So, if I use some kind cooling system (heat sink, thermoelectric cooling), then I can take any laser diode and convert it into a pulsed laser diode (by creating an appropriate laser driver, I presume)?

Comment: @Andyaka And thank you for the advice. I will look elsewhere for more reputable alternatives. But as I said, I'm more-so interested in this as a general question, rather than for any particular laser diode.

Comment: You definitely need to know the time it takes for the laser to start lasing - this is why in comms (modulation) we don't take the low power level below a certain (temperature related) threshold - if we did, speed (modulation on-off speed) would be abysmal. That problem may also be a problem for pulsed laser applications - I don't know.

Comment: @ThePointer my point was that you can pulse it, but how do you know how much you can pulse it by? Normal LEDs will generally tolerate PWM of a few times the rated current for short duty cycle. Without a spec you have no way of knowing other than winding the power up until your diode explodes ...

Comment: https://www.newport.com/medias/sys_master/images/images/ha6/h59/8797049618462/AN11-Pulsing-a-Laser-Diode.pdf further reading

Comment: I think it would be a lot more effective to give specs you are aiming for (repetition rate, pulse energy, duty cycle) and your application (ablation, time of flight, etc) and then ask about how to build a driver for that specification. Those specs are going to change the solution from being trivial to expensive to completely impossible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Often, a pulsed laser diode is just one that is not very efficient, so that if it were operated continuously (we say "continuous wave" or "CW") it would overheat and destroy itself. Most often the first lasers designed of any particular type (including the first laser ever, a pulsed ruby laser) are pulsed, and only later are more efficient ones capable of CW designed. This includes laser diodes.

So you can certainly take any laser diode and operate it pulsed.

Doing it practically will have a few difficulties.

- If you want to achieve very short pulses, and the laser isn't designed for that (very low capacitance, mainly, when we talk about laser diodes), then you might not be able to get the pulse width you want with any particular laser.
- If the laser isn't characterized for pulsed operation, you won't know how strong a pulse (what pulse energy) you can drive without damaging the device or reducing its lifetime.
- If you want a very particular laser wavelength, you might find the laser produces a slightly different one when operated pulsed than it does when operated CW.

Also, if you want pulses in the 1-100 ns range, and not too much peak power, and are willing to do some experimentation (and destroy a few lasers) to find how hard you can drive your laser without damage, then you will probably be able to do it. If you want sub-nanosecond pulses (and particularly if you want 10 ps or less), you'll probably want to choose a different laser type with a gain-switching or mode-locking mechanism and a longer cavity to achieve that. Diode-pumped fiber ring lasers seem to be quite popular for producing sub-picosecond pulses, for example, depending on the desired wavelength.

Comment: The first part of your last paragraph describes my requirements precisely! I’m looking for 1-100 ns pulse width, low peak power (for biomedical applications, and require skin/eye safety), and wavelength will be in the NIR range. I’m thinking of getting some cheap 800nm diodes and using them for experimentation, and then moving on to the higher wavelength, more expensive diodes when I have a better idea of how to implement the idea. Since you seem to have a good idea of what I’m interested in, do you have any resources/suggestions/advice/ect.?

Comment: (In particular, how to go about converting a continuous laser diode into a pulsed one, related mathematics for doing calculations of the characteristics of the new laser, etc.? Textbook references would be fine, if you know of any that have sections focusing on this.)

Comment: It shouldn't be too hard to get a 10 ns or longer pulse out of just about any low-power NIR laser just using a pulsed current source to drive it. Getting shorter pulses will depend on the exact laser chosen. The only other thing is if this product needs to last more than maybe 100 hours, you need to take design for reliability seriously. In my work (telecommunications) we typically use over 100 lasers for reliability studies for any new product, for example leaving them running for months at elevated temperatures, to prove out the reliability.

Comment: My original concern was that continuous laser diodes cannot be converted to pulsed lasers, since pulsed lasers require some mechanism of accumulating energy in the cavity and then dumping it out, whereas continuous-wave lasers do not possess this capability. Outside of laser diodes, active or passive q-switching is used for this. So, just to clarify, are you saying that continuous laser diodes actually possess this capability to accumulate energy and dump it in pulses? I just want to be sure, because obviously this is different from generating pulses by “switching it on and off”.

Comment: @The Pointer They don't accumulate any significant energy like a mode locked laser does. You're just turning them on and off really quickly.

Comment: @user1850479 oh, ok. I suspected that would be the case. Assuming I do take a continuous laser diode and pulse it in this way (“turning it off and on”), do you know how I would calculate the new characteristics of the laser, such as the new average output energy, as well as the pulse energies?

Comment: @The Pointer You would measure those parameters, or else pay for a pulsed laser where someone has characterized it for you.

Comment: @user1850479 they *must* be measured? There’s no way to calculate/derive them from the values of the continuous laser, as well as how you choose to pulse it?

Comment: @ThePointer, no general way. Maybe there's some vendor out there that has a device that's characterized both ways and they know, for their process and geometry, how the pulsed parameters relate to the CW parameters. But if you don't happen to be buying that product from that vendor, their knowledge won't apply (and they won't share it with you anyway).